# Mac cannot read .img file

Tags: macos, ubuntu, sd-card

I'm trying to load a disk image onto a SD card and for some reason Mac OS X (El Capitan) cannot recognize the .img file or there is something else wrong with the dd command that is giving me a misleading error.

when I execute:

```
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-rpi2.img of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=32m
```

I get:

```
dd: ~/Downloads/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-rpi2.img: No such file or directory
```

when I run:

```
open ~/Downloads/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-rpi2.img
```

a disk is installed I think. This is what it looks like.

[image]

I'm confused because the .img file is readable by some programs but not the dd command

Comment: `sudo file ~/Downloads/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-rpi2.img` ?

Comment: /Users/CulloFiles/Downloads/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-rpi2.img: x86 boot sector; partition 1: ID=0xc, active, starthead 0, startsector 8192, 131072 sectors; partition 2: ID=0x83, starthead 3, startsector 139264, 2097152 sectors; partition 3: ID=0x83, starthead 3, startsector 2236416, 2097152 sectors; partition 4: ID=0x83, starthead 3, startsector 4333568, 3282944 sectors, code offset 0xb8 @techraf

Comment: Did you type the full `dd` command or did you copy the string from a web browser? It might contain a Unicode hyphen.

Comment: I did copy it from a web browser, but I just re-typed the dd command and still got the error message @techraf

Comment: `sudo dd if=/User/CulloFiles/Downloads/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-rpi2.img of=/dev/null bs=32m` and without `sudo`?

Comment: same error message, with and without @techraf

Comment: Can you check if os is not blocking the file for being downloaded from the internet? First `xattr ~/Downloads/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-rpi2.img` then remove what shows, most likely `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine ~/Downloads/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-rpi2.img` or remove all extended attributes `xattr -c` on this file.

Comment: ...although I checked it and it does not prevent `dd`

Comment: the first command doesn't give any errors and the second one gives me an error that says no such xattr com.apple.quarantine. @techraf

Comment: What's definitely broken is that your `dd` error message contains `~` while even if the given file does not exist, bash does substitute it with home directory and the error message contains absolute path. What shell do you use? Are you sure you ran the command with full path a few comments above?

Comment: @techraf absolute path solved it, it was just Users instead of User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

You need either to use an absolute or a relative path as an argument to `dd`:

```
sudo dd if=/Users/<username>/Downloads/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-rpi2.img of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=32m
```

or

```
cd ~
sudo dd if=Downloads/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-rpi2.img of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=32m
```

**Analysis**

Your shell does not expand `~` to your home directory. From the data included in question there ist no way to tell the exact reason.

The `~` in your call comes inside the string and maybe that's what is confusing the shell you are using.

On the other hand Bash resolves this syntax correctly and in case of non-existing file you should see the following response:

```
# sudo dd if=~/Downloads/dummy.file of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=32m
dd: /Users/CulloFiles/Downloads/dummy.file: No such file or directory
```